# SharePoint 2013 Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have documents held in a SharePoint document library. I was a workflow that moves a document from one document library to another BUT if a document with the same name exists in the library that the document is moved to I want it to be added as a new version keeping the previous version history from the document that it has replaced.

E.g.

Doc A moved to Library x
Doc already exists in Library x called Doc A
Doc A replaced Doc A but keeps all DOC a versioning held in Library x

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking someone to write the workflow for you? what have you tried? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117952/can-a-workflow-move-a-document OR http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112331/use-workflow-to-move-document-within-document-library-to-different-folder-in-sam

Comment: Didn't want anyone to write it - share point workflows are completely new to me! I've managed a work around with moving the documents with the workflow designer but have no idea of any other was to make workflows or how to control the versioning!

Comment: Versioning is controlled in list settings.  you should turn on versioning for a list and as you upload a new version of the file it will create versions

Comment: Glenn, enabling versioning is necessary but not sufficient when moving or copying a file amongst SharePoint locations. If a file at folder1/abc.txt is moved into folder2/abc.txt, the original versions of folder2/abc.txt are destroyed and not appended-to.

Answer (score 0):

Go to library / list settings >> Versioning Settings
Set "Yes" where is says " Create a version each time you edit an item in this list? "
Then what you need will happen automatically.

Comment: Adi Solar, this is not the case when moving or copying a file amongst SharePoint locations. If a file of that name already exists, the source versions are retained and the original versions in the destination are obliterated.